# The function $f$ is defined, for $x \geq 0$ , by $f(x) = 4-3\cos (x/2)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $f(na + b) = 2.5$, where $a$ is positive constant and $n = 0, 1, 2,...$, find the smallest possible value of $b$ and least value of $a$.

By substituting $n= 0$, I can get $b$ to be $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. However, I don't understand why $a$ is $4\pi$.

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that the period of the function is $4\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, we need to solve in $(a,b)$ as: $$4-3\cos(\frac{na+b}{2})=2.5$$ $$\implies \cos(\frac{na+b}{2})=\frac{1}{2} = \cos \frac{\pi}{3}$$ Note the solution to $\cos x = \cos y$ is given by $x=y + 2\pi \alpha\,, \alpha \in \mathbb Z$.

Thus, we get: $$\frac{na+b}{2} = \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi \alpha$$ $$na+b = \color{green}{\frac{2\pi}{3}}+\color{red}{4\pi}\alpha$$ Can you take it from here?